# What does [val... ].^2 mean?

Tags: matlab

I'm porting matlab code to python and come across the code below. Looks like it creates a matrix but I'm not sure what the shape of the matrix would be. Can anybody help me understand what this code mean especially '...' and '].^2'?

```
somevarialbe = [var1...
                var2...
                var3].^2;
```

Comment: You can type `help ...` in MATLAB, it’ll tell you what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the item-wise operator and power each item to 2. In the other words, it is equivalent to the following code:

```
somevarialbe = [var1^2...
            var2^2...
            var3^2];
```

And `...` means next line in the code. Hence, it is equivalent to the following code:

```
somevarialbe = [var1^2 var2^2 var3^2];
```

Comment: I see. What does '...' mean?